# d3.js Update circle on line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm posting there because I couldn't find something on other post or on google.

http://jsfiddle.net/CUQaN/9/

As you can see on the JS fiddle, I have a line chart with circle on each point.
I want to update this chart with new data. The problem is that I can receive less or more point than I already have on the graph. For example, I can have 8 point on my line chart and then when I'm updating the chart, I can have just 4, or even 15 point. And my circle are not updating properly because I'm just changing the value of the circle which already exist.
But I really don't know how to update them properly.

I can have that data sometimes :

```
            var data = [
                {"date":"4-May-12","close":Math.random()*568.13,"open":Math.random()*35.12},
                {"date":"3-May-12","close":Math.random()*568.13,"open":Math.random()*35.12},
                {"date":"2-May-12","close":Math.random()*568.13,"open":Math.random()*35.12},
                {"date":"1-May-12","close":Math.random()*568.13,"open":Math.random()*35.12},
                {"date":"30-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*354.98,"open":Math.random()*424.56},
                {"date":"27-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*24.00,"open":Math.random()*253.89},
                {"date":"26-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*490.70,"open":Math.random()*215.54},
                {"date":"25-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*42.00,"open":Math.random()*351.23},
                {"date":"24-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*210.28,"open":Math.random()*20.23},
                {"date":"23-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*20.70,"open":Math.random()*368.34},
                {"date":"20-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*412.98,"open":Math.random()*42},
                {"date":"19-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*26.44,"open":Math.random()*20.56},
                {"date":"18-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*48.34,"open":Math.random()*356.45},
                {"date":"17-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*26.44,"open":Math.random()*20.56},
                {"date":"15-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*48.34,"open":Math.random()*356.45},
            ];
```

And just that data other times : (more or less)

```
            var data = [
                {"date":"4-May-12","close":Math.random()*568.13,"open":Math.random()*35.12},
                {"date":"3-May-12","close":Math.random()*568.13,"open":Math.random()*35.12},
                {"date":"2-May-12","close":Math.random()*568.13,"open":Math.random()*35.12},
                {"date":"1-May-12","close":Math.random()*568.13,"open":Math.random()*35.12},
                {"date":"30-Apr-12","close":Math.random()*354.98,"open":Math.random()*424.56},
            ];
```

Is someone can help me please ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This is pretty much the standard update pattern, covered e.g. [here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to remove the old points and add the new ones rather than trying to move them. To do this you can use an id function to make the points unique - see [here](http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html)

A small example:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(myData, function(d) { return d.x; })
    .enter()
    .append("circle");
```

The important part here is that points are identified by their x-value, rather than their index in the data point array. Infact this might help in your current situation as the points will only move up/down and not side to side.

Comment: Yes, I know, I've already think about that :
When the line is at the bottom :
- Add new points with other className at the bottom
- Remove the previous circles
- Move the new circles and lines

But It will be better if I just add/remove few circle and not delete everything all the time.